# How to change all the keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this `{'lastname':'John', 'fistname':'Doe', 'id':'xxxxx'}`
and I would like to add a prefix to all key values. The outcome should look like
`{'contact_lastname':'John', 'contact_fistname':'Doe', 'contact_id':'xxxxx'}`

I tried to achieve this by a lambda function, but did not work.

```
original = {'lastname':'John', 'fistname':'Doe', 'id':'xxxxx'}
modified = {(lambda k: 'contact_'+k) :v for k,v in original}
```

But it gives me an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean `original.items()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to correct your code, you can iterate over `key`s and create `tuple(k, v)` and pass it to `dict`.

```
modified = dict(('contact_'+k, original[k]) for k in original)
```

Or you can use `dict comprehension` & `f-string`.

```
original= {'lastname':'John', 'fistname':'Doe', 'id':'xxxxx'}

modified = {f'contact_{k}' : v for k,v in original.items()}

print(modified)
```

---

```
{'contact_lastname': 'John', 'contact_fistname': 'Doe', 'contact_id': 'xxxxx'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of `dict.pop()`:

```py
original = {'lastname':'John', 'fistname':'Doe', 'id':'xxxxx'}

for k in original.keys():
    original[f"contact_{k}"] = original.pop(k)

print(original)
```

Output:

```py
{'contact_lastname': 'John', 'contact_fistname': 'Doe', 'contact_id': 'xxxxx'}
```